# Force linking of work items to VS git commits

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

Is it possible to force a developer when committing work through Visual Studio to link a work item (Bug, Task, Product Backlog)?

I can see I can link with a '#' in the git commit comments but would like this to be mandatory on all commits? i.e. the commit will fail if not linked to a work item?

Comment: does it have to be in the comments? we usually link them in the pull request instead. we squash commits from local before a push so commit messages can be re-written then. we don't want to put any kind of hurdle between the dev and local commits or pushes to their feature branch. its caused too much lost or inaccessible code, when it only exists on some dev laptop, and that guy is out today.

Comment: So long as we can force commits to be linked to work items, but i don't see anywhere we can restrict commits not linked. We use devops

Answer (score 0):

It is possible on the pull request level. You may add the branch policy to require linked work items: [Check for linked work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#check-for-linked-work-items)

[image]